# How to Sum two or more similar tables

Tags: mysql

There is any way to sum the values of two similar tables in MySQL?

For example, I have the two following tables:

Table 1:

```
id | field1 | field2 | ... | fieldN
1  |   5    |   6    | ... |  32
2  |   25   |   5    | ... |  2
...|  ...   |  ...   | ... | ...
N  |   4    |   1    | ... |  30
```

Table 2 :

```
id | field1 | field2 | ... | fieldN
1  |   4    |   5    | ... |  4
2  |   2    |   5    | ... |  3
...|  ...   |  ...   | ... | ...
N  |   4    |   5    | ... |  0
```

I'm thinking to use a UNION ALL on that tables, because the tables has the same fields, following by a SUM on every field GROUP BY the ID.

In the first query I'll get:

```
id | field1 | field2 | ... | fieldN
1  |   5    |   6    | ... |  32
1  |   4    |   5    | ... |  4
2  |   25   |   5    | ... |  2
2  |   2    |   5    | ... |  3
...|  ...   |  ...   | ... | ...
N  |   4    |   1    | ... |  30
N  |   4    |   5    | ... |  0
```

... and at last the SUM:

```
id | field1 | field2 | ... | fieldN
1  |   9    |   11   | ... |  38
2  |   27   |   10   | ... |  5
...|  ...   |  ...   | ... | ...
N  |   8    |   6    | ... |  30
```

There is an alternative way to do that ?

Comment: no there is nothing to do your way is fine.

Comment: if you have two similar tables that why dont you combine them in one table?

Comment: Because they have diferent purpose. The first table contains the consuming forecast of a specific stock item by month whereas the second table contains the quantity to receive in purchase orders by month.

Comment: this could have been simply handeled by adding a single column type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two choices.

The first is to do a join, assuming they have the same ids:

```
select t1.id, (t1.field1 + t2.field1) as Field1, . . .
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
```

You can, of course, change this to a `left outer join`, but then you have to handle NULL values in the arithmetic calculations.

The second is your method:

```
select id, sum(field1) as Field1, . . .
from ((select t1.*
       from t1
      ) union all
      (select t2.*
       from t2
      )
     ) t
group by id
```

Which you do is somewhat a matter of preference.  I tend to think that the `join` will optimize better (particularly with the right indexes).  However, if the set of ids is different in the two tables, the `union all` more easily handles that case.